# Why does it return true?

Tags: php

I can't seem to find the problem.

```
// Check that someone from this IP didn't register a user within the last hour (DoS prevention)
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM accounts WHERE registration_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'  AND registered > ".(time() - 3600));

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $errors[] = 'To prevent registration flooding, at least an hour has to pass between registrations from the same IP. Sorry for the inconvenience.';
}
```

Why does this always return true no matter what? Even if the accounts table is empty.

Comment: a count like that returns one row of of data, containing the result of the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even there is 0 rows that match your condition, it'll simply return  this.

```
+-----------+
| COUNT(id) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

Because you wanted the `count` of rows. Its `0`. Hence there is **one row**.

Here is how you should handle it.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query));
$count = intval($row[0]);
mysqli_free_result($query);

if ($count > 0)
....
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken your data will always be 1 line saying the value of the count (since you're using count).

Comment: Yes, so even if the count is 0, you the query will return count with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the returned rows not the value. So check like that

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query));
$count = $row[0];

if ($count > 0)
{

}
```